# Field XXX in XXXXX required a bean of type 'java.util.Map' that could not be found. Spring with MySql

Tags: java, spring

in my project, I have a login manager class - that calls to "tokenManager" class.
the tokenManager class included a map of tokens, and save there the generated tokens.

I get this error message:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field tokens in com.chana.login.TokenManager required a bean of type 'java.util.Map' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.Map' in your configuration.
```

The tokenManager class defines a bean of type "map" (with @Autowired)
so I don't know how to resolve that.
Does anyone have an idea?

tokenManager.class:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TokenManager {
    @Autowired
    private Map<String, TokenInfo> tokens;
    
    public boolean isTokenExists(String token) {
        return tokens.get(token) != null;
    }
    
    public String generageToken(ClientType type) {
        TokenInfo info = TokenInfo.generate(type);
        tokens.put(info.getToken(), info);
        return info.getToken();
                                        
    }
    public void removeToken(String token) {
        tokens.remove(token);
    }
    private boolean isTokenExpired(Date time) {
        return new Date().after(DateUtils.addMinutes(time, 30));
    }
    public void removeExpired() {
        tokens.entrySet().removeIf((entry)-> 
                isTokenExpired(entry.getValue().getCreationDate()));
    }
}
```

The loginManager.class call to tokenManager.class:

```
@Component
public class LoginManager {
    private final ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private final AdminService adminService;
    @Autowired
    private TokenManager tokenManager ;
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;
    
    @Autowired

    public LoginManager(ApplicationContext context, AdminService adminService, TokenManager tokenManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.adminService = adminService;
        this.tokenManager = tokenManager;
    }

//continue...
```

Comment: Provide a bean of type Map.

Comment: Why do you want to have the token map as bean? It should be enough to have it as a regular field in the TokenManager.

Comment: @dunni because it saves the token (as key) with object (as value) of "tokenInfo" including the date, (to remove the token after some time) and clientType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of autowire in the `TokenManager`

```
    @Service
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class TokenManager {
        private Map<String, TokenInfo> tokens = new HashMap<>();
...
```

This should be enough

Comment: thank you! after removing @Autowired and adding the new statement. 
but the autowired annotation do the same, so why it doesn't work?

Comment: No, Autowired doesn’t do the same as the new operator. With Autowired, Spring will look for a configured bean with that type and try to inject it. So you would have to create that bean somewhere. Spring doesn’t just do magic.

Comment: Autowired annotation injects already created bean configured using different spring annotations so its aware of those. It then matches these by type or name to inject into another bean. So in this case you don't have any configured bean type of Map so it fails